# collection [] method broken in 2.1.9 for ranges?

Tags: orientdb

I've got these classes in my schema:

```
create class hour extends V
create class minute extends V
create class tdindex extends V

create property hour.hour integer
create property hour.minute linkmap minute

create property minute.index linkset tdindex
```

When I query single values from 'hour' linkmap I get different 'minute' records than when I query ranges:

```
orientdb {db=rawxp}> select expand(minute[29]) from hour where hour=7   

----+-------+------+-----
#   |@RID   |@CLASS|index
----+-------+------+-----
0   |#13:449|minute|[281]
----+-------+------+-----

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.002 sec(s).
orientdb {db=rawxp}> select expand(minute[30]) from hour where hour=7

----+-------+------+-----
#   |@RID   |@CLASS|index
----+-------+------+-----
0   |#13:450|minute|[289]
----+-------+------+-----

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.002 sec(s).
orientdb {db=rawxp}> select expand(minute[29-30]) from hour where hour=7

----+-------+------+-----
#   |@RID   |@CLASS|index
----+-------+------+-----
0   |#13:448|minute|[287]
1   |#13:451|minute|[283]
----+-------+------+-----

2 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.002 sec(s).
```

Isn't that a bug?  Or am I misunderstanding how the range query is supposed to work?

When I take a look at the records, #13:449 and #13:450 are indeed the correct results that I'd expect for that last query.

Here's another query result:

```
orientdb {db=rawxp}> select expand(minute[29,30]) from hour where hour=7 

----+-------+------+-----
#   |@RID   |@CLASS|index
----+-------+------+-----
0   |#13:449|minute|[281]
1   |#13:450|minute|[289]
----+-------+------+-----

2 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.023 sec(s).
```

That looks correct, so the comma operator appears to work ok.

Here's a link to the database that exhibits this problem (compressed with bz2 or gzip): https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7gmW6cqkVoHWnNVMnhLaGJkYzA&usp=sharing

Comment: Hi 8forty, do you have a simple dataset/db to share ?

Comment: @8forty I have problems when I try to extract the file

Comment: @8forty, could you try with select expand(minute[29,30]) from hour where hour=7 ?

Comment: I edited the original question adding output of the query you requested

Comment: Hi @8forty I will post my previous comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query

```
select expand(minute[29,30]) from hour where hour=7
```

EDIT

You can use this query

```
SELECT expand(minute["29-35"]) FROM hour where hour=7
```

Comment: Ok, but that might not give good performance where I need to do a range a few hundred or more.  Could you add to your answer whether the range query is actually broken (a bug), or am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: adding quotes around the numbers doesn't work: "select expand(minute["29-30"]) from hour where hour=7" returns the same incorrect results

Comment: Hi @8forty, you are right, I have tried with "SELECT expand(minute["28-31"]) FROM hour where hour=7" and it works but "SELECT expand(minute["27-31"]) FROM hour where hour=7" don't works. I see that you have created the issue https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5666